# Thoughts on novelty: Making a mobile product when there is already a desktop version?

Tags: patentability, patent-infringement, novelty

I am thinking of making a certain consumer product. There is a similar product on the market that is designed to be used on a desktop and is quite large. (To the best of my knowledge it is not patented today, if that has any bearing on the answer).

The product I am thinking of is designed to be mobile (can be used in any position, not necessarily standing on a desktop) and significantly smaller.

What are your thoughts on this – is making a product mobile and smaller enough to fulfill the requirements of novelty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Novelty is easy, non-obviousness is hard. Yes it will be novel but will it also be obvious? Generally, making something smaller, bigger, lighter, heavier would be considered obvious unless there was a trick to accomplishing it. If a mobile version benefits from a user interface change or the addition of features those might be elements that can add up to non-obviousness.

Comment: Thank you! The product would have quite a different user interface and would have, at least in part, a different technology inside to accomplish its task – that makes me think it is non-obvious 
(but the question isn't obvious :) )